# How to install a crash handler on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, crash-reports

How can AppEngine's Java flavour be configured to capture all exceptions?

The idea would to send an email when this happens.

On AppEngine Python + Django this is trivial to do (just configure Django properly), but on the Java flavour I feel it should also be simple but probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

You can install your own [Error Handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Error_Handlers) by catching generic exception:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

Then you can have a servlet at `/errors` that does whatever you like, usually logging the error and displaying a proper response to user.

Answer (score 0):

Just put an exception around your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        safeMain(args);
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        emailCrashInfo(e);
    }
}

public static void safeMain(String[] args) {
    // Your normal main method
}
```

Comment: You even might want to catch `Throwable`